# Phantom wallet extension not detected using @solana/wallet-adapter-react

Tags: phantom, react

i'm currently building a react-native webapp. My phantom wallet extension network is changed to 127.0.0.1:8899, but the app seems to not be able to detect the phantom wallet itself. Would appreciate any help I can get. Here's some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: the quality of this question would be greatly improved by replacing these screenshots with code blocks.  folks aren't generally interested in retyping code from scratch to reproduce

Comment: hey @trent.sol thanks for your feedback. Will do so the next time. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

so i managed to figure out a work around with the help of @moraispgsi from https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/412

seems like there's a need to specify the exact folder to import from [image]

instead of "import { useWallet...} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react

Comment: That's odd. I am importing from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react" and it works just fine...

Comment: @sohrab Do you happen to be building on react native as well?

Comment: I did a while ago but my current one is plain react. Things may have changed...